# ActiveX Control won't automatically update

Tags: activex

How do I get an ActiveX control to automatically update on the clients computer?

First of all, in order for the client to install the ActiveX the first time the user needs to run IE "as administrator" (if in Windows 7) and this will install the component correctly.  If there is an update to the ActiveX I replace the cab file with the new version.  This will update the ActiveX using a browser on the same server as the website.  But any other computer it will not update the ActiveX control.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: The same way that blasted Adobe Flash updater does it, nagging relentlessly every time I restart my machine.  If it is just a single DLL then you can rename the file to replace it, even if it is loaded in IE.

Comment: hi @dcinadr I want to know how do you update the ActiveX control in the client machine. I have also created two cab files (1.0.0 and 1.0.1) and installed in the system 1.0.0. Now when i update replace the cab file withe newer it is nor asking for installing.

Comment: I never got it to AUTOMATICALLY update on the clients computer.  We decided that it was acceptable for the user to be prompted with a new install when there is an update.  Not sure if there is another way around this.  Good luck.